# jQuery remove options from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a page with 5 selects that all have a class name 'ct'. I need to remove the option with a value of 'X' from each select while running an onclick event. My code is:

```
$(".ct").each(function() {
    $(this).find('X').remove();
   });
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This work well:

`$('select').children('option[value="X"]').remove();`

Answer (score 543, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".ct option[value='X']").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Or to be more terse, this will work just as well:

```
$(".ct option[value='X']").remove();
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. What's the sytax to limit this to .ct with a selected value = '' ?

Comment: This is the easiest if you don't need to know the value. For example removing the first option

$("#affiliate")[0][0].remove();

Answer (score 67):

```
$('.ct option').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == 'X' ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Or just

```
$('.ct option[value="X"]').remove();
```

Main point is that `find` takes a selector string, by feeding it `x` you are looking for elements named `x`.

Comment: +1 i like this answer i think its better because i can test 'X' as like or part of the `value` for `<select>` element

Comment: I used this answer as i had to remove all the options other than val = 0. i used != 0 and worked like charm :)

Answer (score 38):

`find()` takes a selector, not a value.  This means you need to use it in the same way you would use the regular jQuery function (`$('selector')`).

Therefore you need to do something like this:

```
$(this).find('[value="X"]').remove();
```

See the jQuery [find](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find) docs.

Comment: much better in the case where you're passing a variable to the append

Answer (score 10):

It works on either option tag or text field:

```
$("#idname option[value='option1']").remove();
```

Comment: The precise targeting and simplicity here are worth noting

Answer (score 6):

If no id or class were available for the option values, one can remove all  the values from dropdown as below

```
$(this).find('select').find('option[value]').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterating a list and removing multiple items using a find.
Response contains an array of integers. $('#OneSelectList') is a select list.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Controller/Action",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        // Take out excluded years.
        $.each(response, function (j, responseYear) {
            $('#OneSelectList').find('[value="' + responseYear + '"]').remove();
        });
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Something that has quickly become my favorite thing to do with removing an `option` is not to remove it at all. This method is beneficial for those who want to remove the `option` but might want to re-add it later, and make sure that it's added back in the correct order.

First, I actually `disable` that option.

```
$("#mySelect").change(
    function() {

        $("#mySelect").children('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop("disabled", true);

        $("#re-addOption").click(
            function() {
                $("#mySelect").children('option[value="' + howeverYouStoredTheValueHere + '"]').prop("disabled", false);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

and then to clean up, in my CSS, I set `disabled` `option`s to be hidden, because hiding an `option` in some browsers doesn't work, but using the method above, clients with those browsers wont be able to select the option again.

```
select option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

Personally, on the `re-addOption` element, I have a custom property of `data-target="value"`, and in place of `howeverYouStoredTheValueHere`, I use `$(this).attr('data-target')`.

Answer (score 3):

**To remove all Options**

```
$(".select").empty();
```

**To remove all Options and add a blank option**

```
$(".select").empty().append(new Option('--Select--',''));
```

Answer (score 1):

if your dropdown is in a table and you do not have id for it then you can use the following jquery:

```
var select_object = purchasing_table.rows[row_index].cells[cell_index].childNodes[1];
$(select_object).find('option[value='+site_name+']').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

For jquery < 1.8 you can use :

```
$('#selectedId option').slice(index1,index2).remove()
```

to remove a especific range of the select options.

Answer (score 1):

When I did just a remove the option remained in the ddl on the view, but was gone in the html (if u inspect the page)

```
$("#ddlSelectList option[value='2']").remove(); //removes the option with value = 2
$('#ddlSelectList').val('').trigger('chosen:updated'); //refreshes the drop down list
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for remove the selected

```
$('#btn-remove').click(function () {
    $('.ct option:selected').each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code:

`$("#select-list").empty()`