# Two dropdowns with non-identical options that restrict each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdowns with non-identical options but the same number of options. Using javascript (and jQuery 1.11.1) I need either dropdown to restrict (by disabling, not hiding) the options available in the other dropdown to the next option and below.

I.E:

```
<select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="0">option1_1</option> **
    <option value="0">option1_2</option> **
    <option value="1">option1_3</option> **DISABLED**
    <option value="2">option1_4</option> **DISABLED**
    <option value="3">option1_5</option> **DISABLED**
</select>

<select id="dropdown2">
    <option value="0">option2_1</option> **DISABLED**
    <option value="0">option2_2</option> **DISABLED**
    <option value="0">option2_3</option> **
    <option value="1">option2_4</option> **
    <option value="2">option2_5</option> **
</select>
```

If option 2 in dropdown1 is selected, options 1 & 2 of dropdown2 are disabled and only the remaining options are available in dropdown2 and the unused options in dropdown1 would also be disabled. Dropdown2 would control dropdown1 in the same way if the initial choice was made in dropdown2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that at time of writing I hadn't tried anything because I was stuck on how to start (i'm a novice). But, I just found this question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573893/restricting-range-of-drop-down-lists the answer to which does what I'm after except that after selecting one option in one list the first remaining option in the other list is the equivalent option. I need the equivalent option to be disabled with the next option after that as the start of the available options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var index;
        $('#dropdown1').change(function ()
            {
            $('#dropdown2 option').removeAttr('disabled');
            index = $(this).find('option:selected').index() + 1;
            $('#dropdown2').find("option:lt(" + index + ")").prop("disabled", true);

            $('#dropdown1').find("option:gt(" + $(this).find('option:selected').index() + ")").prop("disabled", true);
            index = index -1;
            $('#dropdown1').find("option:lt(" + index + ")").prop("disabled", true);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Shriya R. Though I do need dropdown2 to also control dropdown1 so I modded your code to include control from dropdown2 to dropdown1 by duplicating the change function and swapping the dropdown names and that seems to work.

Comment: didnt notice that the change u want in dropdown2 :). u got it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the requirement by using `disable` property.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYkVW/299/).

```
$("select#dropdown1 option[value*='1'],select#dropdown1 option[value*='2'],select#dropdown1 option[value*='3'],select#dropdown2 option[value*='0']").prop('disabled',true);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

-Help :)