# HTML Drop Down List - tidy up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I've implemented a html drop down list and all seems to be fine, would just like to tidy it up:

1) When the order screen loads 'Select' appears as the initial option on the drop down. When the user clicks the drop down the 'select' still appears. I would like to hide 'select' when the drop down is being selected, some option in the view I am missing?

2) validation wise, I cant make an order until an option is selected from the drop down. This is fine however where before I was using a text box and got a nice big red error message, now I get nothing, How can I notify the user an option has to be chosen?

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Selected_BicycleModelId, Model.BicycleModels, "Select")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order.BicycleModel)
</div>
```

**Update**

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => x.Selected_BicycleModelId)`

has resolved the validation message issue (thanks Roman Ko). anyone ideas on the 'select' dissapearing - JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => x.Selected_BicycleModelId)
```

When it comes to the 'select' caption, you can try to remove it using - for example - jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#Selected_BicycleModelId', function () {
   $("#Selected_BicycleModelId option[value='']").each(function () {
       $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

See [jQuery remove options from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518216/jquery-remove-options-from-select) for more detailed info.

Comment: Wow. Good catch. I totally did not see that at all. Sheesh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply roman, that resolved the validation msg, still working on the 'select' though

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not possible. The `<select>` element has no ability to provide a placeholder value. As a result, a common workaround, and the same that Razor employs, is to add another option with an empty `value` attribute. This appears in the dropdown because it is very much an option like any other in that list. It's your form validation, both client-side and server-side that makes it not a "valid" option.
2. <del>You'll need to provide more information to determine why the validation is no longer working. In particular, the property and any associated attributes from your model would be helpful.</del> See @RomanKo's answer. I don't want to steal his thunder by just posting the same thing here. For my part, I totally missed it.