# jQuery remove options from select without value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ignore/remove all options from a select box that either have a blank value or don't have the **value=""** attribute at all, e.g.

```
<option>Any Option</option>
<option value="">Any Option</option>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  // Create the dropdown base
  $("<select />").appendTo("#pagination_container");

  // Create default option "Go to..."
  $("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Select Page..."
  }).appendTo("#pagination_container select");

  // Populate dropdown with menu items
  $("#pagination_container a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
      "value"   : el.attr("href"),
      "text"    : el.text()
    }).appendTo("#pagination_container select");
  });

  $("#pagination_container select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });

});
```

Comment: Please post your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a two-part selector to achieve that:

```
$('option[value=""],option:not([value])').remove();
```

**NOTE**: Bear in mind that `value=""` checks the initial state of the elements. Therefore if you later change the value of the element, and not necessarily the value attribute, then you may get unexpected results. If the values of the `option` elements are bound to change, please use `filter()` instead of `[value=""]`.

Answer (score 1):

Target the elements like this

```
$('option[value=""]');
```

and to remove do this

```
$('option[value=""]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#pagination_container").find("option").each(function(index, el){
  var $el = $(el);
  var value = $el.attr("value");
  if (value === "" || value === undefined)
    $el.remove();
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set.
>   [source](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,  this solution solves my another problem

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to this questions:

- [jQuery remove options from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518216/jquery-remove-options-from-select)
- [Removing an item from a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box)

Check the links and learn a lot of diferents way to solve your problem.