# Populate dropdown list upon selecting a value from same dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a drop down which has some set of values. Once I select the value from the dropdown list and I can see that filter is happening. If I want to filter the another value from the dropdwon then I have to do refresh without refresh the filtering is not happening. Overall If I select the value from the dropdown the filter is happening if I want to see the filter for next value I have to do refresh without refresh the filter is not happening.
Here is my HTMl code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="statusFilter">
        <option value="">statuses</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>

    </select>
</div><script>
    $("#statusFilter").on('change',function(){
        var dropdownvalue = document.getElementById("statusFilter")
        var selectStatus = dropdownvalue.options[dropdownvalue.selectedIndex].value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/status/filter',
            data:{
                'selectedstatus':selectStatus
            },
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result)
                if (result=='error'){
                    alert("There are no status value")
                    document.location.href="/status";
                }
                else{
                document.write(result);
            }}
        })
    })
</script>
```

I am not showing the entire backend

```
if len(status_list) > 0:
        return render_template("status_list.html",result=status_list)

    else:
        result = 'error'
        return result
```

is there any way we can filter the selected values without refresh in dropdown?

My backend is returning the list if it has some values or it returns error

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what `/status/filter` returns. `document.write` will definitely not be the answer, though. More likely something like setting `dropdownvalue.innerHTML`.

Comment: I have added the backend code

Comment: Sure.  Don't use document.write().  Instead, iterate over the dropdown options and remove or hide the ones you don't want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery remove options from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518216/jquery-remove-options-from-select)

Comment: No it didnt work for me

Comment: What I need is I select 'A' and the list will be filtered. SO If I want to select 'B' I have to do refresh then only filter happens.is there any way we can select value for 'B' without refresh?